# E-mail piping with e-mail forwarder does not work

Tags: php, email, pipe

I have a simple email pipe script. But I need a copy of the  incoming e-mail going to another e-mail address. Unfortunately I do not receive the e-mail as I wanted.

The code;

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
$email_msg = ''; // the content of the email that is being piped
$email_addr = 'sales@flensmuts.nl'; // where the email will be sent
$subject = 'Piped:'; // the subject of the email being sent
// open a handle to the email
$fh = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
// read through the email until the end
while (!feof($fh)){
    $email_msg .= fread($fh, 1024);
}
fclose($fh);
// send a copy of the email to your account
mail($email_addr, $subject, "Piped Email: ".$email_msg);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mail server logs will probably say something about this. My guess is that it might be failing because your message is malformed because of the prefix you're adding. Try sending the message untouched, like this:

```
mail($email_addr, $subject, $email_msg);
```

Separately, for simple forwarding like this, you can probably set up your mail server to do this directly without having to go via a script.

Comment: Hi Synchro, I will try the suggestion.

Comment: Normally my mail server could do such a forwarder automatically, but it is to an external e-mailadress, which doesn't work. My hosting provider can't help me either, so I need to be creative..

Comment: Well, bear in mind that the PHP mail function just opens an SMTP connection to localhost, so it’s unlikely to behave much differently.

Comment: Hi! Yes I know. The problem of the webhosting is that de forwarders tries to send as the sender, but if I script a PHP mail the mail will be sent as my mail server. Directly mailing from the mailserver to the receiver works correctly. It is only the forwarder that gives me problems.

Comment: "bear in mind that the PHP mail function just opens an SMTP connection to localhost" - really? Only on a ms-windows host with a local MTA.

Comment: Yes, and that’s why it tends not to work on Windows. On Linux there is usually a local mail server for it to use. This is one of the key reasons that PHPMailer came into being in the first place - user-space access to remote SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error checking in your script. There is no instrumentation in your script to see if it is even being run. You have not said why you believe that the script is being triggered. You have not said how mail() works on your test site.

Decompose the issues. Replace this script with one which dumps stein to a file to find out if there is an issue with the input integration.

Write and run a script which sends an email when using mail() when manually invoked. If you control the MTA then read your logs - even if these experiments are successful.

Then go back to your original script. Add some logging. Check the value returned by mail(). Check that the delivery path accepts forwarded mail with a broken envelope.